# type 'X' is not a direct type of 'Y' - but with std::conditional

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming, conditional-compilation

I have a Base class, two classes inheriting from that base class (they are slightly different from each other) and a Last class which can either inherit from `Derived1` or `Derived2` based on a template. I use `std::conditional` to determine at compile time which `DerivedX` it should actually use:

```cpp
template< class >
class Base;

template< class T, class ...Args >
class Base < T(Args...) >
{
public:
    Base(int a) { std::cout << "Base constructor " << a << std::endl; }
};

template< class >
class Derived1;

template< class ...Args >
class Derived1 < void(Args...) > : public Base< void(Args...) >
{
public:
    Derived1(int a) : Base< void(Args...) >(a)
        { std::cout << "Derived1 constructor " << a << std::endl; }
};

template< class >
class Derived2;

template< class T, class ...Args >
class Derived2 < T(Args...) > : public Base< T(Args...) >
{
public:
    Derived2(int a) : Base< T(Args...) >(a)
        { std::cout << "Derived2 constructor " << a << std::endl; }
};

template< class >
class Last;

template< class T, class ...Args >
class Last< T(Args...) > : public std::conditional<
    std::is_void<T>::value,
    Derived1< void(Args...) >,
    Derived2< T(Args...) > >
{
public:
    Last(int a) : std::conditional<
        std::is_void<T>::value,
        Derived1< void(Args...) >,
        Derived2< T(Args...) > >::type(a)
    { std::cout << "Last constructor " << a << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Last<int(int)> last(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I have read multiple topics about diamond heritage and virtual inheritance and I get the same error as those topics: `type Derived2<...> is not a base class of Last<...>`. However these topics never use an `std::conditional`. Btw it compiled fine until I try to instantiate a `Last` object. Is there something I'm missing ? Is it even possible to do it like that ?

Comment: Suggest having a `template<typename T> using ProperDerived = typename std::conditional<...>::type;` and using that everywhere. This might actually solve the issue if it's a missing `typename`.

Comment: I don't really understand where to put that `using` statement and how to use it but you made me notice I forgot to put `::type` after specifying my inheritance type in the `Last` class declaration

Comment: Significant typo: `template< class T, class ...Args >class Last< T(Args...) > : public std::conditional< //`. Should be `conditional_t` or `::type` at the end. With that fixed, it compiles fine I think: https://godbolt.org/z/WannsGG89

Comment: As for where to put `using`: anywhere after all the bases classes, really: https://godbolt.org/z/KaWhfvqKe

Comment: I feel like I tried exactly that, but it didn't work, thank you for sharing that code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your declaration of the base class:

```
template< class T, class ...Args >
class Last< T(Args...) > : public std::conditional<
    std::is_void<T>::value,
    Derived1< void(Args...) >,
    Derived2< T(Args...) > >
{
...
}
```

You either need to say `public std::conditional_t` (where the `_t` is very important at the end), or else you need to put `::type` after the `std::conditional` template parameters, as in the following:

```
template< class T, class ...Args >
class Last< T(Args...) > : public std::conditional<
    std::is_void<T>::value,
    Derived1< void(Args...) >,
    Derived2< T(Args...) > >::type
{
...
}
```

Otherwise, your base type is `std::conditional` and you are trying to mem-initialize `Derived2`, which is not the same type.